# Microsoft Graph API for OOO message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was working with the Microsoft graph APIs and was wondering if there was an API for setting Out of Office messages for a user?

The documentation doesn't seem to have this feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Graph API - Out of Office Auto reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797515/microsoft-graph-api-out-of-office-auto-reply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [automaticRepliesSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/automaticrepliessetting) property in [user mailbox settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update-mailboxsettings). That should be the one you are looking for.

The properties you can use are similar to what you have in [Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration) so:

```
externalAudience
externalReplyMessage
internalReplyMessage
scheduledEndDateTime
scheduledStartDateTime
status
```