# Microsoft Graph API - Out of Office Auto reply

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

There are Microsoft Graph APIs to get Outlook properties such as a profile, meetings, email, etc. but I am interested in setting the "Out Of Office" auto-reply using Microsoft Graph.

I have used Graph's `findRoom`, `findMeetingTimes` and other endpoints but couldn't able to figure out the API for setting "Out of Office".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Graph API for OOO message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795142/microsoft-graph-api-for-ooo-message)